# How to remove duplicate code in QT project files?

Tags: c++, qt, openapi-generator

I have an old QT project file which contains multiple times nearly the same configuration section. This configuration section basically downloads a certain verison of the open-api generator, generates QT code stubs with the open-api generator and adds the code generation to the pre-target dependencies of QT such that it is called "automatically".

**Simplified example of the section:**

```
OPENAPI_CLI_VERSION = 4.2.3
codegentemp1.target = .codegentemp1
codegentemp1.commands = \
  echo $$PWD/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/api-spec-1.yml \
  $${OPENAPI_CLI_VERSION}.jar ... \
  touch $$codegentemp1.target
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += codegentemp1
PRE_TARGETDEPS += .codegentemp1
```

This section is copied multiple times and only a few variables change, e.g.:

- api-spec-1.yml, api-spec-2.yml, api-spec-3.yml, ...
- codegentemp1,
  codegentemp2, codegentemp3, ...

and a few variables remain fixed, e.g.:

- OPENAPI_CLI_VERSION

**Question:**

Is it possible to move this section into something like a function in QT project files and call this function e.g. with:

- generate_api(4.2.3, codegentemp1, api_spec-1.yml)

Thanks in advance!

**Update 1**

I want basically to assign the ".commands" field some redundant Shell Script code which contains varible arguments such as the open api CLI version (which might changes per each assignment), i.e. something like:

```
func1(openapiversion, targetname) {
  echo $$PWD/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/api-spec-1.yml
  OPENAPI-$$openapiversion.jar ...
  touch $$targetname
}

OPENAPI_CLI_VERSION = 4.2.3
codegentemp1.target = .codegentemp1
codegentemp1.commands = func1($$OPENAPI_CLI_VERSION, $$codegentemp1.target)
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += codegentemp1
PRE_TARGETDEPS += .codegentemp1
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the [qmake language manual](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html) says how to create your own functions, just under [the section on the replace functions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#replace-functions):

```
defineReplace(functionName){
    #function code
}
```

Comment: Wow I missed that in the spec. Good to know!

Comment: I think this does not answer my real questions, which I have maybe not described very well.I use the "Adding custom targets" function from QT with the "codegentemp1.commands = ..." (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html).

With defineReplace I do not know, how I can achieve the same result as my code above.

Basically I tried that already following:
defineReplace(func) {
    targetName = $$1
    echo "HELLO WORLD"$$targetName
}

codegen1.target = .codegen1
codegen1.commands = $$func("TEST123")
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += codegen1
PRE_TARGETDEPS += .codegen1